# jQuery tablesorter working with tablesorterPager and hidden rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, pagination, tablesorter

I currently have a large result set in a table where I am applying and removing a class of 'hidden' (display:none) to certain rows based on other filters within the page. I'm able to get [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/index.html) working with the zebra widget, but when I try to include [tablesorterPager](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-pager.html) on it, the script dies without any errors.

I've tried removing the 'hidden' class from the table rows, and it limits the results, but doesn't create the pagination controls and if you try to sort, the results disappear and the script dies.

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    widthFixed:true,
    widgets: ['zebra']}
).tablesorterPager({
    container: $("#pager")
});
```

That's the code that's called on document ready.

At any given time, here's a few sample rows of data (pre-tablesorter):

```
<tr class="place hidden">
    <td class="name">Sample Row 1</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>0</td>
</tr>
<tr class="place">
    <td class="name">Sample Row 2</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>0</td>
</tr>
<tr class="place hidden">
    <td class="name">Sample Row 3</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>0</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Do you have your table rows in a tbody, a thead for your sortable rows and your pager form floating outside of the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the complete pager DOM structure as so:

```
  <div id="pager" class="pager">
<form>
  <img src="javascript/jqPlugins/tablesorter/addons/pager/icons/first.png" class="first"/>
  <img src="javascript/jqPlugins/tablesorter/addons/pager/icons/prev.png" class="prev"/>
  <input type="text" class="pagedisplay"/>
  <img src="javascript/jqPlugins/tablesorter/addons/pager/icons/next.png" class="next"/>
  <img src="javascript/jqPlugins/tablesorter/addons/pager/icons/last.png" class="last"/>
  <select class="pagesize">
    <option selected="selected"  value="10">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option  value="40">40</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Also note that the zip I downloaded did not contain any  of the image files since the 'icons' folder is missing. Also annoying was the fact that the zip contained svn repo folders. So you have to add this 'icons' folder and the image files within. You can download the images files from the tablesorter example page for the pager. I also had to set my path directly to the images (notice in my code sample I do that). Good luck!

Comment: thx it took me forever i love the plugin but the instructions are very weak,i had to download the images seperated also :) (you forgot the closeing </div>)

Answer (score 1):

```
            this.construct = function(settings) {

            return this.each(function() {   

                config = $.extend(this.config, $.tablesorterPager.defaults, settings);

                var table = this, pager = config.container;

                $(this).trigger("appendCache");

                config.size = parseInt($(".pagesize",pager).val());

                $(config.cssFirst,pager).click(function() {
                    moveToFirstPage(table);
                    return false;
                });
                $(config.cssNext,pager).click(function() {
                    moveToNextPage(table);
                    return false;
                });
                $(config.cssPrev,pager).click(function() {
                    moveToPrevPage(table);
                    return false;
                });
                $(config.cssLast,pager).click(function() {
                    moveToLastPage(table);
                    return false;
                });
                $(config.cssPageSize,pager).change(function() {
                    setPageSize(table,parseInt($(this).val()));
                    return false;
                });
```

This is the constructor for the tableSorter Pager plugin.  As you can see it binds click functions to elements based on the config (cssFirst, cssNext, cssPrev, cssLast ).  Unfortunately this means those elements must already exists in the container defined by 'config.container'  This doesn't seem to be documented anywhere on the pager plugin site.  But you must define (in html,  or with javascript before the call to the pager function)  elements with the following default classes:

```
            cssNext: '.next',
            cssPrev: '.prev',
            cssFirst: '.first',
            cssLast: '.last',
```

I'm not sure how the table sorter will interact with your hidden rows,  you may need to make some modifications to the core tableSorter functionality to get the behavior you're looking for.

/Chris

Comment: Thanks Chris. This kind of died off because we went in the direction of lazy-loading results. I'll play around a bit more with tablesorter's core and post up a solution if I find it.